# Selecting nearby table rows with other class name and toggling the class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table displayed in HTML which has two kinds of class

1 - alt
2 - SelectedrowData

initially the  will have class "alt" when clicked the class will be changed to "SelectedrowData". At the same time remaining  whose class was "SelectedrowData" should to be retained to "alt".

In simple words. **When I click on a row the class name should be toggled**. Same follows when I click on other rows. In fact in the **whole table there will be only 1 "SelectedrowData"**

My table is as below

```
    <table>
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td>72</td>
        <td>SALES DEPT. SALES STAFF</td>
        <td class="fieldHide">7018072</td>
        <td class="fieldHide">7018572</td>
        <td class="fieldHide">7018072</td>
        <td class="fieldHide">7018072</td>
        <td class="fieldHide">6</td>
        <td class="fieldHide"></td>
        <td>Default</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="SelectedrowData">
        <td>73</td>
        <td>SALES DEPT. OFFICE ADMIN</td>
        <td class="fieldHide">7018073</td>
        <td class="fieldHide">7018573</td>
        <td class="fieldHide">7018073</td>
        <td class="fieldHide">7018073</td>
        <td class="fieldHide">7</td>
        <td class="fieldHide"></td>
        <td>Default</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="alt">
        <td>72</td>
        <td>SALES</td>
        <td class="fieldHide">7018072</td>
        <td class="fieldHide">7018572</td>
        <td class="fieldHide">7018072</td>
        <td class="fieldHide">7018072</td>
        <td class="fieldHide">6</td>
        <td class="fieldHide"></td>
        <td>Default</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: <tr> in the example is missing. Please consider <tr> in the explanation if you find it difficult to understand.

Comment: I have tried with this just to chnage the present clicked table row. $(this).removeClass("alt").addClass("SelectedrowData"); Next i want how I can change rest of the row classes to "alt"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('tr').click(function(){
       $(this).attr('class', 'SelectedrowData')
       .siblings().attr('class', 'alt');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('tbody tr').click(function(){
   // First, make all the tr's have the 'alt' class
   $('tbody tr').attr('class','alt');

   // Now make this tr the one with the unique class
   $(this).attr('class', 'SelectedrowData');
});
```

Comment: I agree with the code. I am looking for the code which is converting the "SelectedrowData" class of the row back to "alt".

Answer (score 0):

If it's the whole table, just do:

```
$('tr').on('click', function() {
    $(".SelectedrowData").add(this).toggleClass('alt SelectedrowData');
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/vtCqU/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
$('table').click(function(e){
    var $clickedRow;
    if(e.target.nodeName === 'TR') {
        $clickedRow = $(e.target);
    } else {
        if($(e.target).parents('tr').length > 0) {
            $clickedRow = $(e.target).parents('tr');
        } else {
            $clickedRow = undefined;
        }
    }

    if($clickedRow) {
        $('.SelectedrowData').removeClass('SelectedrowData');
        $clickedRow.removeClass('alt').addClass('SelectedrowData');
    } 
});
```

This will handle clicks on both tr and td.